# Spark action workflow job fails - unable to connect to ResourceManager

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

Spark workflow job is stuck in RUNNING state as it tries to connect to the Resource Manager using the default address: 0.0.0.0:8032.

In the job.properties, the namenode and jobtracker address:port have been correctly set to the yarn.resourcemanager.address and port in yarn-site.xml.

As seen in the logs below, the MR task tries to connect to the ResourceManager at the correct address only once and then on tries to connect using the default address:

```
2015-09-07 04:33:30,865 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
2015-09-07 04:33:31,213 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-172-31-15-94.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.15.94:8032
2015-09-07 04:33:32,109 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2015-09-07 04:33:33,120 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032.** Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-09-07 04:33:34,121 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Before running the Oozie job, I export YARN_CONF_DIR and HADOOP_CONF_DIR to /etc/hadoop/conf (where yarn-site.xml is present) as well.
I am trying the example Spark workflow job that comes with the Oozie archive (http://archive.apache.org/dist/oozie/4.2.0/). The MapReduce, Shell and Java workflow examples all work fine.

job.properties:

```
nameNode=hdfs://ip-172-31-15-93.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020
jobTracker=ip-172-31-15-94.us-west-2.compute.internal:8032
master=yarn-client
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/apps/spark
```

workflow.xml:

```
<workflow-app xmlns=’uri:oozie:workflow:0.5′ name=’SparkFileCopy’>
<start to=’spark-node’ />

<action name=’spark-node’>
<spark xmlns=”uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1″>
<job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
<name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
<prepare>
<delete path=”${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/spark”/>
</prepare>
<master>${master}</master>
<name>Spark-FileCopy</name>
<class>org.apache.oozie.example.SparkFileCopy</class>
<jar>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/apps/spark/lib/oozie-examples-4.2.0.jar</jar>
<arg>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/data/data.txt</arg>
<arg>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/spark</arg>
</spark>
<ok to=”end” />
<error to=”fail” />
</action>

<kill name=”fail”>
<message>Workflow failed, error
message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
</message>
</kill>
<end name=’end’ />
</workflow-app>
```

I am running the oozie job as user oozie.

Environment: Hortonworks Data Platform 2.3. Oozie v4.2, Spark 1.3.1 on a small cluster (2 datanodes, 1 namenode) setup in EC2.

Am I missing any other configurations / key steps? Any leads on this will be of immense help.

Comment: I am also getting the same error... Any updates since September?

Comment: This issue got resolved..its been six months and I unfortunately don't remember the fix. Perhaps the issue was with the jobTracker port. I see that we are using port 8050.